# Is there a way to get progress messages from Grpc-request

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

We have Grpc-api in our asp net core api. Some of our operations takes a long time. Can I in some easy way send back progress message to my client?

Like "Reading from provider 1...", "Reading from provider 2... ", "Calculating stuff...".

Since the final result is a small message and take short time to send back I dont think its meaningful to stream back data, its the processing that takes time.

I have tried to google, but with great failures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gRPC doesn't support RPC "progress" reporting out of the box, because it's not a functionality that belongs into gRPC. gRPC is a library and cannot know what you consider "progress" in your particular application and your particular protobuf service definitions.

So the solution is to implement progress reporting in your application logic on top of gRPC. One neat way of doing that is to define a custom "protocol" on top of a server-streaming call. The responses can be a protobuf "oneof" message with submessages depending on what the server wants to report. E.g. in each of the responses received by the client, the server can express either the current progress info ("ProgressInfo" message) or the actual result ("ComputationResult" message). Note that this is only way of implementing the progress reporting, but it sounds like to most straightforward one to me.

Comment: Ok, kool. I was something along those lines, but before I did something custom Id throught I ask.Im going to call it, AreWeThereYet. Thanks for the clarification